# Extracting Object values from a Queryset without a for loop

Tags: django

I have a model called

```
class UserTag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique= True)
  users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I am trying to filter its contents based on the user like this

```
usertags = UserTag.objects.filter(users=request.user)
```

now I want a list of all the tag names for this particular query. I know I can probably use a loop

```
for tag in usertags:
  tags.append(tag.name)
```

But what if a user has a 1000 tags? wont this slow down the response?
Is there a more efficient way to handling this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want the tag names, use a `values_list` query:

```
tags = UserTag.objects.filter(users=request.user).values_list('name', flat=True)
```